# Visual Studio: can I automatically add an entry to app.config when I add a library to references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I sometimes have common libraries that require some config information. The config information would come from the app.config of the app that the library is added to. For example lets say the library needs to know where to find something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TaskManagerFolder" value="\\server9\Data\BCC\FS\Jobs" />
</appSettings>
```

The key is required by the library and the value is determined by the app or the installation of that app.

Right now the only way I know how to get that lined added to the app.config is to document that it's required and have it manually added.

I would like to add a config file to the library project with some default value and automatically have that merged into the app.config when the library is added to the app project.

Does this make sense? Is there a way to do what I want or is there a better way to handle the whole thing that would not require an config entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes".  But you must provide your library as a [Nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) package (rather than just manually add a reference for a .dll in the MSVS IDE).

Here are two links that give you more details:

- [Nuget Package creation workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/overview-and-workflow)
- [Nuget: Transforming source code and configuration files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations)